# Replace statment with email address using (OSX) sed

Tags: excel, macos, sed, grep

I have a [*iqy* file](https://fileinfo.com/extension/iqy) that I am stripping down. I have `grep` stripping out the *url* into a new text file. The new text file has:

```html
["emailaddress","Please enter your email address:"]
```

I need to replace that whole statement with an email address. I cannot get `sed` to work properly on OS X.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "whole statement"?  Do you want to replace the whole line, or do you want output of the form `["emailaddress","actual@address"]`, or something else?

Comment: Clarify what `I cannot get sed to work properly` means. You probably don't take your car to a mechanic and just say `I can't get the car to work properly` and then walk away expecting her to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If your text file looks like that:

*test.txt*

```
first line
["emailaddress","Please enter your email address:"]
last line
```

You can use the following sed statement to replace the searchtext with john.doe@aol.com

```
sed "s/\[\"emailaddress\".*\]/john.doe@aol.com/g" test.txt > new.txt
```

or inplace

```
sed -i "s/\[\"emailaddress\".*\]/john.doe@aol.com/g" test.txt
```

result:

```
first line
john.doe@aol.com
last line
```

Comment: Thanks UtLox. I was missing the "\" before and after the first bracket. I could not figure out why it was giving me a bracket error. I appreciate the help.